# Alamofire not saving file to disk

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a video file on S3 that I am trying to save to disk. However, if the file already exists on disk, I want to overwrite it. I wrote this function to download the file but it never saves the file. I can see the progress % increasing. But, how do I access the resulting file and save it to disk?

```
    var finalPath: NSURL?

    Alamofire.download(.GET, s3Url) { temporaryURL, response in
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
            let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename
            finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
            println(finalPath)
            //remove the file if it exists
            if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(finalPath!.absoluteString!) {
                println("file exists on disk, removing..")
                fileManager.removeItemAtPath(finalPath!.absoluteString!, error: nil)
            }
            return finalPath!
        }

        return temporaryURL
    }
    .validate()

    .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
        let progress = (Double(totalBytesRead) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToRead)) * 100
        println(String(format: "%.2f", progress))
    }

    .response { request, response, data, error in
            println(request)
            println(response)

        if let mediaData = data {
            println("saving file to disk")
            mediaData.writeToURL(finalPath!, atomically: true)
        }
    }
```

Normally I would use the example provided in the docs, but It fails if the file already exists. ie:

```
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
```

So, how can I download the file, overwrite it if it exists and record the path that the file is written to to my coreData database?

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the file first. Alamofire only tries to move the file from the temp location to the final location that you provide in the `destination` closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension on `Alamofire.DownloadRequest` to provide options for how to download the file where you can use the option `DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions.removePreviousFile`.

for details on how to do that see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42866104/3395921) question.