# Check if a file already exists before downloading it with Alamofire + suggestedDownloadDestination

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I check if a given file has been already downloaded before re-downloading it by using Alamofire? I'm using `suggestedDownloadDestination` so Alamofire will automatically choose the name of the file and save it in the choosen directory, for example the `.CachesDirectory`. The problem is that the value given by `suggestedDownloadDestination` is of type `DownloadFileDestination` which will return a `NSURL` only by calling him with the request's `response`, but in this way I could not ever know the file path without performing a request before.

This is the code I currently use to download a file with Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, downloadLink, destination: destination).progress {
                    bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in

                    }.response {
                        request, response, data, error in

                        guard error == nil else {
                            return
                        }

                        // This will give me the file path but we're already in a Request!
                        print("\(destination(NSURL(string: "")!, response!))")
                }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @osrl Unfortunately enough Alamofire does not give you the opportunity to do this easily as you would use suggestedDownloadDestination, I have fixes using a custom path for the download directory and remove suggestedDownloadDestination

Comment: I tried `.head` method to find out the destination file path, and check if it exists before downloading the file. But Alamofire creates the file even if the download request method is `.head`. So that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you figured this out yet, but you can create an extension over `Alamofire.DownloadRequest` like:

```
extension Alamofire.DownloadRequest {
    open class func suggestedDownloadDestination(
        for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory = .documentDirectory,
        in domain: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask = .userDomainMask,
        with options: DownloadOptions)
        -> DownloadFileDestination
    {
        return { temporaryURL, response in
                let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: directory, in: domain)(temporaryURL, response)
            return (destination.destinationURL, options)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can specify in the options parameter if you want the file to be overwritten:

```
let destination =  DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .cachesDirectory,
                                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                with: [DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions.removePreviousFile])
```

Comment: 1.) Question is - how to know file already exists/downloaded , not how to handle that situation.... 
2.) If file already exists then it should not be downloaded again... as in my case...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which I used

1. Download a file
2. check if it exist if so just return the path otherwise

```
  func downloadDocumentFile(filePath: String,onDownloadProgress: @escaping(_ progress: Double) -> Void,onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void,onSuccess: @escaping(_ destinationUrl: URL) -> Void){
        guard let url = URL(string: filePath) else {
            onError("Couldn't create url from passed file path")
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        Alamofire.download(url, to: destination)
            .downloadProgress { (progress) in
                onDownloadProgress(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
        .responseData(queue: .main) { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let destinationUrl = response.destinationURL {
                    onSuccess(destinationUrl)
                }else {
                    onError("Couldn't get destination url")
                    assertionFailure()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                  // check if file exists before
                if let destinationURL = response.destinationURL {
                    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path){
                        // File exists, so no need to override it. simply return the path.
                        onSuccess(destinationURL)
                        print()
                    }else {
                        onError(error.localizedDescription)
                        assertionFailure()
                    }
                }else {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    assertionFailure()
                }
            }

        }
    }
```